# split and loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby but the problem which I am trying to solve is bit logical.

I am getting a list of users who count is around 3000.
but the api supports the response limit to 250 and also it does not support pagination or offset.
So I have to hit this api in a loop such a way that every time I will get 250 records till I reach the count 3000.
and on each round I am assigning some attributes to it.

api is a Get Request which fetch the list of users.
`api url: {{baseUrl}}/accounts/:id/users?limit=250&offset=0&count=true`

`api says - offset is record based, not page based,`

`How can I requests for users such as: First call for 0 to 250 then 250 to 500 then 500 to 750 till we reach the max count.`

To generalize this I am thinking that whatever the count I will get it should loop through all and assign attributes.

Comment: Please describe in a bit more detail what you need (i.e. what kind of input the API takes). Do you have a list of 3000 IDs, and you need to request with sublists of up to 250 items? Do you request by offset and limit (e.g. 250 items from 0, 250 items from 250, 250 items from 500...)?

Comment: Thanks @Amadan I have updated the description

Comment: _"it does not support pagination or offset"_ – what do you mean by that? The API clearly has an `offset` parameter.

Comment: `api url: {{baseUrl}}/accounts/:id/users?limit=0&offset=0&count=true` maybe? I'd give it a go.

Comment: I tried by giving both 0 but it didnt work. It takes default for limit and 0 for offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be using [`Range#step`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-step)?

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

(0..3000).step(250) do |offset|
  uri = URI("#{base_url}/accounts/users?limit=250&offset=#{offset}")
  res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

  puts res.body if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
end
```

Or may be such way with [endless range](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#class-Range-label-Endless+Ranges)

```
(0..).step(250) do |offset|
  uri = URI("#{base_url}/accounts/users?limit=250&offset=#{offset}")
  res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

  if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
    puts res.body
  else
    break
  end
end
```

You can also can use [`redo`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-redo+Statement) in the block to repeat bad request

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Numeric#step` to enumerate a sequence of offsets `[0, 250, 500... 2750]`. Then, assuming `get_stuff` returns an `Array`, you can stitch the results using `Enumerator#flat_map`:

```
stuff = 0.step(by:250, to:2999).flat_map do |offset|
  get_stuff(offset, 250)
end
```