# Updating same hash in iterator each loop in ruby

Tags: ruby

Updated with getEntitlementList() method
I am new to ruby and trying to update hash with data getting in steps.
Short story: I got my other problem solved and it was on this:
[1]: [split and loop in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72470078/split-and-loop-in-ruby?noredirect=1#comment128036728_72470078)

It has 2 problems:

1. Even though I am setting offset step wise by 250, it is returning the same response. For ex: offset=0. offset=250, offset=500 till offset=3000. It is returning same response not different.
2. On every new offset, I want to update the same hash so that in the end I will have hash for all items.

API Doc says:

1. limit >> Integer that specifies the maximum number of records to return in a single API call. If not specified a default limit will be used.    Maxiumum of 250 records per page

   2.offset >> Integer that specifies the offset of the first result
   from the beginning of the collection. offset is record based,
   not page based, and the index starts at 0.
   For example, offset=0 and limit=20 will return records 0-19, while offset=1 and limit=20 will return records 1-20. Between 0 and the last record index.

```
def getEntitlementList(url,header,source,limit,offset)

  # This method pulls list of existing entitlements of a given source
  # This list is  uses to create a hsh Map of displayableName vs Id
  # Returns a hash Map

  uri = URI.parse( "#{url}/cc/api/entitlement/list?limit=#{limit}&offset=#{offset}&CISApplicationId=#{source}" )
  puts uri
  http = Net::HTTP.new( uri.host, uri.port )
  http.use_ssl = true
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new( uri.request_uri, header )
  # puts "request : #{request}"
  response = http.request( request )
  # puts "entitlements hash map : #{response}"
  # puts "#{JSON.parse(response.body)}"
  case response
  when Net::HTTPSuccess
    responseBody = JSON.parse(response.body)
    #      puts responseBody
  when Net::HTTPUnauthorized
    puts "#{source} Entitlements Hash Map creation is a Failure!"
    puts "Error: Unauthorized."
  when Net::HTTPServerError
    puts "#{source} Entitlements Hash Map creation is a Failure!"
    puts "Error: Server Error."
  else
    puts "#{source} Entitlements Hash Map creation is a Failure!"
    puts "Error: #{response.code}"
  end
  return responseBody
end
```

What I want to achieve is, I have below code:

```
      limit = 250
      entitlementHash = Hash.new
    
      (0..3000).step(250) do |offset|
        responseBody = getEntitlementList(url,header,source,limit,offset)
        count = responseBody['count']
        entitlementList = responseBody['items']
    
        entitlementList.each {|a| entitlementHash["#{a['displayableName'].upcase()}"] = 
        a['id']}
    
        puts "updated entitlementHash size: #{entitlementHash.size}"
      end
      return entitlementHash
```

My api has 3000 data items but in each run it pulls only 250.
So every time it pulls the data, I would like to update the `entitlementHash` with newer data.

So that at the end of last run, my `entitlementHash` will have all 3000 data items.
Currently it is just taking last 250 items.

I tried with below:

```
entitlementHash.update
entitlementHash.store
entitlementHash.merge
```

but didn't work.
Any help would be really grateful.

Comment: Are you sure the keys dont overlap? The code seems correct so my assumption is that `displayableName` overlaps.

Comment: displayableName is unique so it will not overlap

Comment: What is the output generated by this line `puts "updated entitlementHash size: #{entitlementHash.size}"` when running the code?

Comment: each time it says: 250 instead of keep on increasing for each 250

Comment: The way it's written, you'll eventually run `getEntitlementList(…)` with `offset == 3000`. What happens then? Also, did you try reviewing the `responseBody` to check if it's returning what you expect it to return? The hash handling part of your function seems fine.

Comment: oh. you were right. even though I am changing the value of offset everytime by 250, it is returning the same response. What needs to be done to get all items?

Comment: That depends a lot on how `getEntitlementList` is defined. :) Update your question with it and I'll try to write an answer.

Comment: updated question with getEntitlementList() method.

Comment: Alright, that should be working correctly, so my guess is that the API does not work like that. You should be able to test it on the browser as well—if you create a URL with `offset=500` and no other parameters, what's the response? Are there any examples in the API docs showing how to get more records? Are there other parameters you might try changing to see what happens?

Comment: by setting only offset param it is returning the same response. I have updated question with API documentation.

Comment: Unless there's a particular reason, why not just get *all* entitlements and then chunk it up on your side? Repeated API calls are expensive, and dealing with offsets (even if the API supports them) is a great way to have fun with off-by-one or out-of-range errors.

Comment: If you get all your items at once, and assuming you're getting back an array of JSON objects, you simplify your problem to `chunks = JSON.parse(response.body).each_slice(250) { do_something_with_chunk _1 }` and let Ruby's built-in methods handle the offsets.

Comment: I tried the request without sending limit and offset params, it still returns the response for 250 items. Not for all entitlements

Comment: Thank you so much all, finally I got it working by sending extra params: count=true, start=0 and then 250 till target. I got these params  from networking tab of developer tools to see how ui is handling. But these params are no where mentioned in api ref guide. once again thank you all.